# OpenAPI 3.0 : C++ server stubs and client SDK

Tags: swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I have OpenAPI 3.0 specifications and want to generate C++ server stubs and client SDK but there is no option on swaggerhub for that. Is there some codegen available for creating it?

Comment: What version of SwaggerHub are you using? Have you tried following these instructions? https://support.smartbear.com/swaggerhub/docs/apis/generating-code/client-sdk.html

Comment: @proslaniec, yes, I checked that. For OpenAPI 3.0, there is no option for C++

Answer (score 1):

Swagger codegen is its own separate open-source project. After quickly looking at the GitHub page, it looks like the standalone project DOES cover C++. The options are as follows:

Server stubs: C++ cpprest, C++ Qt5, C++ Tizen

Client SDKs: C++ Pistache, C++ Restbed

It is also entirely possible to build your own Swagger codegen template. Folks who can't find an existing template that works for them will often create their own template. You can find more information on creating templates here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/wiki/Building-your-own-Templates